# Turn on laptop while folded and without pressing laptop button

Tags: windows, laptop, desktop, switch, cable

Planning to make my windows laptop act as a console and would like to hide it in a tight space which wouldn't allow me unfold my laptop. Would be great if there's an external switch that could be attached to it. Tried searching but all results lead to desktop setups.

Comment: We do that with a dock so that you can run on a closed laptop with an external button. Works fine. Will a dock plus laptop fit in your space?

Comment: If it's only put to sleep/standby and not fully shut down, you should be able to set it up so that any USB input (keyboard, mouse, etc) will wake it up.

Comment: What kind of dock you're using? @John

Comment: Manufacturer's dock for the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you arent the first person to want this, it is not a common request.  Laptops do not come with external power buttons, as they could be accidentally turned on or off.  No one wants to accidentally lose their data, or find out their laptop battery is dead because something pushed/held the button down.

One option would be just to leave your laptop on.  I have a laptop hooked up to a TV for 5 years now and it has (almost) never been turned off.  As long as there is enough airflow to keep it from overheating, there is no reason you could not do this.  I even have it set in BIOS to turn on automatically after a power loss.

Another option would be to use a dock, assuming your laptop supports it and the manufacturer makes one.  Most laptop docks come with power buttons that are accessible without opening the laptop.  Granted, they are also designed not to be put in tight places, so reaching the button might be just as much of a chore as opening the laptop.  Additionally, this assumes the dock fits in the space you want.

Lastly, there is the hack.  A laptop power button is just a button - a momentary switch, to be exact.  You could open up your laptop, find the power button, and solder two thin wires to the power button's solder joints.  Then run the wires out a hole, like a slot for the vents.  I suppose if you had no other choice, you could drill a small hole for the two wires.  Then solder the two wires to a momentary switch.  You can salvage a momentary switch from junk electronics or purchase them from Amazon, eBay, etc.  The cheapest ones cost a few cents, while fancy ones can be a few dollars.  If you know someone who has an Arduino or Raspberry Pi, odds are they have spares.  But thats it, you now have an external power button.

Now in theory, if your laptop is dockable, you could find the pins in the docking port's connector on the laptop and attach it externally.  I have never done this, nor do I know anyone who has, but I would *assume* you could attach a momentary switch to a ground pin and the pin connected to the power button.  But that will depend on how the manufacturer designed the connector.  Then there is the task of finding those pins.  If you are good with a multimeter, its doable.  However, connecting the wires to those pins so they stay, well... that would require soldering to very small pins next to plastic, or glue, or something...  In essence, this is a lot of effort and time and not worth it, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think the most viable option for me is the 1st. Would it be okay for the laptop to be set to sleep instead of shutdown? Would it greatly lessen the life expectancy of the unit specially the hard drive (since it could still be spinning) while asleep or it is too minor to worry about?

Comment: Setting it to sleep should be fine, as long as you can wake it via USB mouse or keyboard.  The hard drive should be fine, as well.  But with the cost of SSDs being so low, why wouldnt you switch to one?

Comment: got hdd as my secondary drive :P . Thanks for the help